# Initialize void pointer to point to an array

Tags: c

Suppose I have the following:

```
typedef struct {
   int itemSize;
   int count;
   void *list;
} Mystruct;

Mystruct *InitStruct(int itemSize, int count) 
{
  Mystruct *my = malloc(sizeof(Mystruct));
  my->itemSize = itemSize;
  my->count = count;
  //What is the best way to initialize list?  For example:
  //my->list = malloc(count * sizeof(void *));   OR
  //my->list = malloc(count * sizeof(itemSize));
}

//The following should return a pointer to the element stored at a given index 
void *Retrieve(const MyStruct *my, int index)
{
   void *item;
   //What is the best way to return a pointer to the item at the given index from 
   //my->list?
}
```

Mystruct is similar to an array and void *list is supposed to store the elements or pointers to the elements.  Mystruct *InitStruct is a function that initializes a Mystruct pointer and void *Retrieve is a function that returns a pointer to the element stored at a given index.

First, how should I initialize void* list?  Should it hold the actual elements or be an array of pointers pointing to the elements?

Second, using the void *Retrieve function, how do I return a pointer to the element stored at a given index in my->list?

Comment: The answer to the question depends on what sorts of things you want to put into that list.

Comment: No, I want it to be general, hence the use of a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first point, if all elements are the same size, as that `itemSize` name suggests, then adding one level of indirection (having `list` point to pointers to items, rather than to items directly) seems to have no added value, so I'd use `my->list = malloc(count * itemSize);`.

On the second point, `(char*)my->list + itemSize*index` should work.  You may first want to check that `index < my->count`, of course (maybe you want to return `NULL` in that case rather than an invalid pointer).

Comment: Yes, I removed any error checking code to make the post as concise as possible.  Why did you typecast my->list with (char *)?  Shouldn't I use (void *)?

Comment: @idealistikz, it's not C-standard-compliant to do address arithmetic on `void*`, e.g. gcc with -pedantic and -Wall would give you a `pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic` warning -- the cast lets the code compile perfectly without warnings even at the highest severity levels, just as it should be.

Comment: sizeof(itemSize) is sizeof(int). I think itemSize should be used directly - malloc(count * itemSize)